# Queue between 2 java application

Tags: java, sockets, queue

i would like to create a Queue between 2 java application(classes)

lets call the first one Farmer , and the second Digger

i would like the first (Farmer) to create a queue 
and the second java application (Digger ) get the queue and process it

very important if the digger class might not run always the Farmer class should wait for digger to work .

```
How could it be done ?  
1. without external server 
2. without files 
3. without DB
```

what is the correct way to do it now-days ?

Comment: looking and a reliable messaging protocol there a bunch of them google for it.

Comment: A class is not an application, as an application can consist of multiple classes. A Java application is a project that consists of *at least* 1 main method, the amount of classes do not matter. Are you sure they are separate applications?

Comment: As for sending a queue across applications, could you serialize the queue and send it via an `ObjectOutputStream`? Or maybe have a separate queue on each program, which stay in-sync via a protocol of some sort (with one application informing the other of mutations, would be a lot cheaper than serializing the queue each time a modification was made)?

Comment: it seems like a school assigment...

Comment: 2 separate application - (i said 1 class to make it simple)  .
what is the best way to transfer data between 2 application when the second one might not always be running . if the second isnt running the first application will wait for the second to start

Comment: @Hector don't solved it just tell how do you transfer data between 2 java application ? how this method of transferring data is called ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that communication using webservices (sending json or xml file between applications) or using [sockets](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Network/0020__Java_Network_TCP_Client_Socket.htm) (sending data by tcp/ip protocol). If you can use frameworks, I recommend give a glance to [Netty Project](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html). With Netty is very easy run a server and connect client application and give a communication.

I Hope it helps.